# Is there any fastet way of adding column with udf functions in huge table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I am trying to add column with UDF function in a huge table which takes lot of time.

Hence, I tried `ADD COLUMN NULL` and `Update SET COLUMN = UDFFunction`. Though this method helped in some way.

The main issue here that table will be populated with new transaction as well. and these computed column will not be populated as its has been created with NULL Value and updated later.

Can we make the below changes in below alter command to run faster?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[ABCD]
    ADD [FAX_1_4] AS ( dbo.udABCD_C11_4( [XMLRECORD] ) ) PERSISTED

GO
```

Comment: I don't believe there's anything _inherently_ wrong with your idea - the only reason it would be slow is if the database was not properly configured (e.g. excessive indexes, insufficient hardware, etc) - or if your UDF did something very inefficiently. Can you post the definition of your `udABCD_C11_4` function?

Comment: Your code adds a persisted computed column - you can't get any faster than that. If you're seeing `NULL` values in your computed column after you (or other programs) perform an `INSERT` then it means your UDF is failing or returning `NULL`. Do you mean to say that it isn't the `[FAX_1_4]` column that is `NULL`, but the `XMLRECORD` column that's `NULL`?

Comment: Thanks Dai. here is the definition of udABCD_C11_4 ...CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].udABCD_C11_4](@xmlrecord XML)     
RETURNS nvarchar(40)     
WITH SCHEMABINDING     
BEGIN     
     RETURN @record.value('(/row/c/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(11)')   
END

Comment: When insert is happening .. TABLE'S COLUMN attribute will be like FAX_1_4 nvarchar null. Thats why when an insert hapens it will be null.. But when use FAX_1_4 udffunction... Automatically it will be populated after extracting XML column value.